# How to change the colors of MapKit Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mapkit

In my app i used mapKit, the problem is the map should be in specific color like this : 
[image: mapKit]
i try to change the type of map, but nothing match with this picture, so i thought if i can change the color of the mapKit. 
anyone faced like this problem ? 
any help please ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/#source) API. I currently have the same problem and this library has come in-handy.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a mask by adding an Overlay betwen the map and Label/Road:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("overlay", ofType: "png")
let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
self.overlay = MKTileOverlay(URLTemplate: fileURL.absoluteString)
self.overlay!.canReplaceMapContent = false
self.mapView.addOverlay(self.overlay!, level: MKOverlayLevel.AboveRoads)
```